# Difficulties proving a remark on when acculumulation points implies convergent subseries on a compact topological space

Tags: general-topology

I am currently studying Topology by working through my lecture notes.
During the lecture our Professor gave a remark which states

> Let $(X,\mathcal{O})$ be a topological space.
> If for all $x\in X$ there is a countable family $\mathcal{O}_X\subset\mathcal{O}$ with
> $U\in\mathcal{O}_x\implies x\in U,\ \forall V\in \mathcal{O},x\in V
> \exists U\in\mathcal{O}_x: U\subset V$
> then an accumulation point implies a convergent subsequence.

As the lecture was not very well structured I am not completly sure if this is even correct. Does anybody of You know that statement to be true?
And if so might have a hint on how to proof it?
Either way I would be very glad.

Edit: Changed "subseries" to "subsequence"

Comment: What do you mean by "accumulation point implies a convergent subseries"? First of all, an implication "X implies Y" only makes sense when X and Y are statements but neither "accumulation point" nor "a convergent subseries" is a statement. Second of all, a (sub)series only makes sense when there is at least a commutative group structure on $X$ which you have not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Given a point $x$, a family $\mathcal{O}_x$ with the properties you've described is called a "local base at $x$".  A space where at every point there is a countable local base is called a "first countable space".  So what you're asking is: Is it true that in a first countable space, every accumulation point of a set is a limit of a sequence from that set?  (At least, I think that's the question: "subseries" is a bit of a strange term to use in this context, as "series" usually refers to infinite summation, which doesn't seem to be what is meant).

It is true; for instance, see [Accumulation points of sequences as limits of subsequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192463/accumulation-points-of-sequences-as-limits-of-subsequences).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
"series" was a tyoo. German is my mother tongue and I frequently mix up sequence and series. I will fix it.